# Difference between results of MATLAB and SPSS Factor Analysis(FA)

Tags: matlab, spss, factor-analysis

This is my code in IBM SPSS:

```
FACTOR 
  /VARIABLES VAR00001 VAR00002 VAR00003 VAR00004 VAR00005 VAR00006 
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /ANALYSIS VAR00001 VAR00002 VAR00003 VAR00004 VAR00005 VAR00006 
  /PRINT UNIVARIATE INITIAL CORRELATION SIG DET KMO INV REPR AIC EXTRACTION ROTATION 
  /PLOT EIGEN ROTATION 
  /CRITERIA MINEIGEN(1) ITERATE(25) 
  /EXTRACTION PC 
  /CRITERIA ITERATE(25) 
  /ROTATION VARIMAX 
  /METHOD=CORRELATION.
```

and this is code of MATLAB R2015b to do the same:

```
[lambda,psi,T,stats,F]=factoran(DATA,2,'rotate','varimax');
```

SPSS output for  roteted component matrix:

```
Rotated Component Matrix    
              Component 
               1      2
VAR00001    .973    -.062
VAR00002    .911    -.134
VAR00003    .833    -.035
VAR00004    .972    -.102
VAR00005    -.236   .823
VAR00006    .062    .878
Extraction Method: Principal Component Analysis. 
 Rotation Method: Varimax with Kaiser Normalization.        
a Rotation converged in 3 iterations.
```

MATLAB `lambda` output:

```
0.993085200854508   -0.0537771548307969
0.875990644597448   -0.147112975689921
0.748570753047806   -0.0343768914779775
0.987459815125692   -0.0988807726538385
-0.203059229288894  0.976610007465447
0.00719025397609984 0.475514010080256
```

Why these outputs are different? I want same results in MATLAB. As you know SPSS ignores eigenvalues smaller than 1. I want same structure in MATLAB. How can I do this?

PS.

MATLAB `T` output:

```
0.622170579007477   -0.782881709211232
0.782881709211232   0.622170579007477
```

MATLAB `psi` output:

```
0.0108898014620571
0.210998162961140
0.438460057014266
0.0151457063113246
0.00500000000002244
0.773834726466399
```

Other SPSS outputs:

```
Component Matrix        
    Component   
              1        2
VAR00001    .964    .144
VAR00002    .919    .061
VAR00003    .821    .141
VAR00004    .971    .105
VAR00005    -.404   .755
VAR00006    -.124   .871
Extraction Method: Principal Component Analysis.        
a 2 components extracted.       


Component Transformation Matrix     
Component   1   2
1   .977    -.211
2   .211    .977
Extraction Method: Principal Component Analysis.  
 Rotation Method: Varimax with Kaiser Normalization.
```

Comment: Part of your code says `Rotation converged in 3 iterations`. This leads me to suspect that the algorithm you are using is stochastic (does not produce the same result every time), or it gives a different answer depending on how you initialize it. Is this the case? If so, that might explain the different outputs.

Comment: @mikkola Thank you for answer. I repeat the process in SPSS but every time i have same results.

Comment: There are so many options to customise that it's hard to say. For example, SPSS says it's using Kaiser normalization but Matlab does not (?). Also, the starting point seems random as per the options in Matlab.

Comment: Have you tried removing the criteria `CRITERIA MINEIGEN(1)` in SPSS to see if you get the same result than Matlab? If so, we'd be sure the difference comes from there

Comment: Here are some answers from stats.stackexchange:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154378/very-different-results-of-principal-component-analysis-in-spss-and-stata-after-r

Comment: @BillBokeey. Chhecked. Same outputs.

Comment: @Oleg. There isn't any option in `factron` function of MATLAB for Kaiser normalization!

Comment: Same outputs in SPSS for both cases or same output than Matlab?

Comment: @BillBokeey Same outputs in SPSS for both cases.

Comment: Can you output the rotation matricx from SPSS and compare it to the matrix T from Matlab output?

Comment: I know, that's probably the main culprit. Force normalization by setting explicitly the option in matlab.

Comment: @Oleg MATLAB documentation : Flag indicating whether the loading matrix should be row-normalized (1) or left unnormalized (0) for 'orthomax' or 'varimax' rotation. Default is 1. --- Set 'normalize' to 0?

Comment: @BillBokeey more information added to the question.

Comment: Problem is that the normalization proposed in Matlab is an Euclidian one and not Kaiser @Oleg

Comment: @BillBokeey Anyway to change default properties of MATLAB in this function or another way to overcome this?

Comment: I think the first question i should've asked is : why do you need the exact same output as the one from SPSS?

Comment: (Implied part of my question is that i don't think it's possible to realize a Kaiser normalization with MATLAB's `factoran`)

Comment: @BillBokeey. I think it is better to answer this question what are differences between these two normalization methods in factor analysis and why SPSS using this normalization method as default and MATLAB using another one as default (without any option to change it in both software)? We can see effects of these normalization methods on results obviously.

Comment: I honestly don't know. For me, these are two ways to calculate approximately the same thing. I'm sure it doesn't change the data analysis to take one or another. If it did, i think there would for sure be a way to specify the normalization you want to use in MATLAB as well as in SPSS

Answer (score 1):

Matlab extracts factors using the maximum likelihood method. I don't think you can change this. SPSS extracts methods using principle components as its default, and this is the method that you have chosen for your SPSS analysis. That's yet another difference...